# How to get IAM apikey and IAM url for Watson Speech to Text?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, credentials, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-tools

I want to play with the IBM Watson Speech to Text Service. How do I get the IAM apikey and the IAM url.

On show credentials, I get this - 
{
  "apikey": "###########",
  "iam_apikey_description": "Auto generated apikey during resource-key operation for Instance - #######",
  "iam_apikey_name": "######",
  "iam_role_crn": "######",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "######",
  "url": "https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
}

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You have the credentials, now what...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [API docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?language=node) to code in a programming language like Node.JS - 
Your `apikey` in the credentials is the IAM_apikey and `url` is the URL in your credentials.

If you are planning to use curl, you can generate an access token using the apikey and url following the instructions [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-iam.html#iam)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the same "basic" authorization to try out any Watson service in Curl:

```
curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "{url}/{method}"
```

replace {apikey} with the ### value you see and replace {url} with that value.

For example,

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:"###########" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/models"
```

See https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text#authentication